# XPath select first node when there is no pcdata before the node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML section like this:

1. `<p><bold>Some Text</bold> some more content and text...</p>`

or

2. `<p>Some Text and something <bold>bold</bold> within and more content...</p>`

I am looking for an `XPath` expressions that returns the element `<bold>` only if it is the first content within `<p>` (like in the first example) and does not return anything if there is `PCDATA` appears before the tag.

I can use `p/bold[1]`, but that returns results for both options.

I'm grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
//p/bold[1][not(preceding-sibling::node())]
```

For all `p` elements, find the first `bold` element, only if it does not have a preceding-sibling - i.e. no PCDATA appears before it.

You could also check the first child node of the `p` element, and check if it is a `bold` element, which could potentially perform faster if there are many children:

```
//p/node()[1][name() = 'bold']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `p/node()[1][self::bold]` to select the first child node if it is a `bold` element.